# Reverse order of class names

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have this mixin function:

```
@mixin doSomething() {

    .theme-x & {
        @content;
    }

}

.class-1 {

  color: 000;

 @include doSomething{

   color: ccc;

   &-element {
     color: #fff;
   }
 }; 
}

// Output
.class-1 {
  color: 0;
}
.theme-x .class-1 {
  color: ccc;
}
.theme-x .class-1-element {
  color: #fff;
}
```

I want this to output this instead:

```
.class-1 {
  color: 0;
}
.theme-x.class-1 {
  color: ccc;
}
.theme-x.class-1 .class-1-element {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Notice the differemce: The theme-x class is on the same element as class-1.

Is this possible?

The real world case is that I have a theming mixin that outputs the .theme-x for several different themes and I want to be able to create child elements that builds on the parent element class name instead of the theme class name...

Comment: Can you create a snippet? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: wouldn't you do `&.theme-x` if you wanted to append it (as it's the 2 classes together, it shouldn't matter which way around it goes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to invert the ampersand and the class of the theme in your mixin to create the desired selector for the main element. To create the sub-element selector, you can assign the class of the main element to a variable and use it inside the content passed to your mixin.

You can also pass your theme name to the mixin to make it reusable for different themes.

See the example below. The use of the variable is a bit less convenient than the ampersand, but it does the job.

```css
@mixin themedWith($theme) {
  $c: & !global;
  &.#{$theme} {
    @content;
  }
}

.class-1 {
  color: blue;

  @include themedWith(theme-x) {
    color: purple;
  
    #{$c}-element {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}

// Output:

.class-1 {
  color: blue;
}
.class-1.theme-x {
  color: purple;
}
.class-1.theme-x .class-1-element {
  color: red;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was hoping that I wouldnt need to use the c variable from the caller of the mixing but I dont see any other way of solving this. I was hoping that someone was smarter than me and could figure out a way :) Thanks.